# react native display location of all files in a folder

Tags: react-native, expo

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, SafeAreaView, Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';


export default function App() {
  
  const [alb,setalb]=useState([''])
  async function permissions(){
    console.log("printing cameraroll")
  const {sp}= await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)


  
  const albums = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync()
  const listOfTitles = albums.map(album => album.title);
  const listofid = albums.map(album => album.id);
 
  
 albu(listofid,listOfTitles)
  }
  async function albu(fn,ld) {
    console.log("entered albu")
  const options={
    album:"WhatsApp Images",
    first:10,

  }
  
 
  
 
  
  let video = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync(ld[1])

  console.log(video.assetCount);
  const ac= video.assetCount    

  const firs = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({album:fn[1],first:100})
  console.log(firs.assets[65].uri)
 
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
      <Button title="Click-me" onPress={permissions} />
      </View>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
  {alb.map((goal) => <Text>{goal}</Text>)}
        </SafeAreaView>
    
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding:Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding:Constants.statusBarHeight
  },
});
```

i am trying to build a app kind of locker with special attributes and security since multiple selection for images is not available for image picker i decided to build my own picker inorder to retrieve all the file location for a given album i decided to use media library api but using the given function i am only able to retrieve few file location rest its showing truncated when i display it in object format or when i try to print file location it gives undefined not a is not a object is there a way for multiple selection of images or to display all the images using media library